# Utilizing collections module in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, collections

Relatively pointed question. Currently running Python 3.4.1 and am just working on an object-orientated exercise where I need to overwrite some functions from an inherited class.

Goal:
importing from builtin module collections and utilizing collections.UserList rewrite the append, extend so that it will not "add" any duplicates if detected. (this part accomplished)

Problem:
The main problem is that I still am learning object oriented programming and I want to build objects which can be easily typed in and returned so I am writing a **str** and **repr** for my class

Currently my class looks like the below: (omitted the "goal" stuff because it works)

```
import collections

class UList (collections.UserList):
    def __init__(self, entry =[]):
        self.entry = entry

    def __str__ (self):
        print (self.entry)
        return

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__str__()
```

Then I decide to run some sample code for good measure:

```
>>> x = UList ([4,5,6])
>>> x.entry
[4, 5, 6]
>>> x
[4, 5, 6]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    x
TypeError: __repr__ returned non-string (type NoneType)
>>> print(x)
[4, 5, 6]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    print(x)
TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type NoneType)
```

usually I look straight to the objects and try to figure out what went wrong but I am a little confused as I am still new =(.  Can someone help explain why it is returning a NoneType even after I have overwritten the **init**? (also, a possible solution on how I can rectify so no error would be extremely helpful)

Comment: Your `__str__` method needs to return a string. As it is now, it returns `None`

Comment: I'm glad you got your question solved! However, please don't edit the fix into the question itself--it makes it difficult to tell what the question originally was, which makes it harder for other users to learn from it. Accepting an answer is already an indication that your question was successfully resolved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider (note no explicit `return` at the end of `__str__`) :

```
>>> class Foo:
...    def __str__(self):
...       print('Foo!!')
... 
>>> f=Foo()
>>> f
<__main__.Foo object at 0x10a655080>
>>> print(f)
Foo!!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type NoneType)
```

Vs:

```
>>> class Foo:
...    def __str__(self):
...       return 'Foo!!!'
... 
>>> f=Foo()
>>> print(f)
Foo!!!
```

The issue is that `__repr__` and `__str__` need to return a return a string. The return from `__repr__` should, if possible, be the 'official' string representation of the object for `eval` to recreate the object or some other `<useful definition>` according the the docs on [__repr__](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__)

The docs on [__str__](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) a more convenient or concise representation can be used' other than a Python expression.